# LibSvm training accuracy

Tags: svm, libsvm

I am using LIBSVM. My data set consists of a training set of 6977 images of faces and non faces. My test is a smaller seperate set of images of faces and non faces. I am trying to perform one class classification so that the machine will recognize whether an image represents a face or not. So far my test results are very satisfying, as the LIBSVM function svmpredit prints an accuracy of 98%.
My question is how can I measure the accuracy in the training procedure?

Comment: Check this out: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Comment: I assume that you mean the accuracy of the training of the best choice of parameters. If so simply `err=svmtrain(y,x,sprintf('-t %g -v 5 -c %g -g %g', cost, gamma))` and save the best err in each loop.